# How to append a whole array to an array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

Say, I have an array with values `(1, 2, 3)` and another one with `(4, 5, 6)`. How can I have a resultant array with values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`?

I tried to use `++`, but that doesn't work. For example, this is what I got in the command shell.

```
scala> val x = Array((1, 2, 3))
x: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((1,2,3))

scala> val y = Array((4, 5, 6))
y: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((4,5,6))

scala> val z = x ++ y
z: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((1,2,3), (4,5,6))
```

Whereas I want `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

**EDIT**

I was actually using array of tuples, my bad. The Array should have been declared as `Array(1, 2, 3)` and not `Array((1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: I never used scala but this seems promissing http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-merging-two-arrays-arraybuffers-joining

Comment: Why is `java` tagged?

Comment: @Pshemo: ++ doesn't combine the Arrays like I want. It would create Array((1,2,3), (4,5,6)), while I want Array(1,2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: @MetallicPriest No, you should try in the REPL:  `Array(1,2,3)`  `Array(4,5,6)` `res0 ++ res1` =>  `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Comment: @AlexisC. I did it in REPL and copied directly from there. It shows me Array((1,2,3), (4,5,6)).

Comment: Well show the exact code you typed with the declarations. Are you sure you didn't do `Array((1,2,3))`? This create an array with one `Tuple3` instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val res = Array(1, 2, 3) ++ Array(4, 5, 6)
```